# I am not able to install file chooser plugin in ionic 2 app?

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am trying to install File chooser plugin in my Ionic 2 app but its showing error regarding git below is my generated error..

```
 Fetching plugin "https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser.git" via git clone
    Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser.git via git.
    Either there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect:
            Error: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe: Command failed with exit code 128 Error output:
    Cloning into 'C:\Users\PLCPL-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\git\1496305068790'...
    fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

Comment: which is your cordova version?

Comment: Is it this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44131995/4826457

Comment: @suraj i am using cordova 6.5.0

Comment: i got success by removing ionic from plugin just install cordova plugin..it will install